# Remove text after @ sign

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-formatting

I am trying to use notepad++ and regular expressions to edit a document.
I have text in this format

```
123.45607894.165@abcd;aba
23.456@av1;084
9871.001@fab:9782581afa
```

And I need to get only the first part of the line , the one before the @ sign. How would I do that to get this:

```
123.45607894.165
23.456
9871.001
```

Answer (score 14):

First, search with **regular expression**:

- open the "**Replace**" dialog (*Ctrl+h*, or menu *Search -> Replace*).
- select the "**Regular expression**" radio button in the bottom-left of the dialog.

Now, fill the following search fields:

- Find what:  `@.*$`
- Replace with:  (leave empty)

This will find the text `@` followed by any number of characters `.*` to the end of the line `$` (end of line part is optional).

The found text is then replaced by nothing (or whatever you want to put in the "Replace with" field).

Answer (score 9):

Find `@.*` and replace with empty string