# Notepad++ Regex assistance needed - removing trailing garbage

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a line in a log that looks like this:

```
Customer-1234567', Site '001', TransferId: '123456789', Authenticated User: 'Customer-1234567|001'
```

I need to remove all the trailing garbage and leave only the customer name and customer number (as above, `'Customer-1234567'`) so I can paste those in a spreadsheet.

I tried doing a search and replace using the following string:

```
'+'$
```

or

```
'*'$
```

...because I thought that this means, 'Start the string with ', match an unlimited number of characters, then end the line with '.'

But it can't find any matches.

Comment: Is the length of 'Customer-1234567' always the same?

Comment: Never the same, no.

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer. Thanks for your help. https://superuser.com/questions/1222441/remove-text-after-sign

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^'[^']+'\K.+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  '             # single quote
  [^']+         # 1 or more not single quote
  '             # single quote
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this position
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Given:**

```
'Customer-1234567', Site '001', TransferId: '123456789', Authenticated User: 'Customer-1234567|001'
```

**Result for given example:**

```
'Customer-1234567'
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]